# how to run a java code from GitHub in windows 10?

Tags: java, windows, github

github URL - https://github.com/ptnplanet/Java-Naive-Bayes-Classifier

I have installed java. how do I run the code?

Comment: This project has no main class. So even you create JAR file and run with javac command, you cannot find anything in your console. So install java IDE (e.g. eclipse, netbeans,etc) then import that project and run junit test class of this project.

Answer (score 1):

The files are uncompiled Java code, you'll need to compile them to Java bytecode (.class files) using the Java Dev Kit (JDK).

Install JDK: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/JDK_Howto.html

Use: http://www.dummies.com/programming/java/how-to-use-the-javac-command/

Comment: Sorry but it's unclear. I install JDK and follow your tutorial but it return me `GoogleDriveFtpAdapter.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
        FtpServerFactory serverFactory = new GFtpServerFactory(controller, cache, configuration, cacheUpdater);
        ^
  symbol:   class FtpServerFactory
  location: class GoogleDriveFtpAdapter`